# Modulo (%) in Tkinter Entry() [Python]

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, calculator

Okay i am currently working on a GUI calculator, and im using Tkinter to help me create this. I wish to create a feature in my program where i have a modulo (%) button and i want to perform the modulo operation and return the number. So i have the user enter 1 number in the entry() and i get the number by doing entry.get() etc. But now how would i get the 2nd number from the entry() and still keep the first one. Basically i want the user to enter the 1st number, press the modulo button and enter the second number then hit enter to get the answer. Can someone please help me out. I could possible attach code to my question but honestly it's not needed, and yes i have a button created allready called modulo_Button with the command=lambda:modulo_Operation() but please tell me what to do in the function.

Code:

```
#Project Name : Calculator ++ [1.8.2]
#Project Written by : Pamal Mangat.
#Project Written on : Wednesday, July 29th, 2015.
#Version 1.8.2 - Includes code improvement, bug fixes, new features and a new look.

from tkinter import *
from sys import *
import pygame
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from math import sqrt

master = Tk()
master.title("Calculator ++ [1.8.2]")

#Main entry
entryVariable = StringVar()
entryTab = Entry(master, relief=RIDGE, textvariable=entryVariable, bd=14, width=43, insertwidth = 1,bg='White',fg='black' ,font = 120, justify=RIGHT)
entryTab.place(x=-1, y=12)
entryTab.focus()

#VersionNum
versionNum = Label(master, text='V[1.8.2]', font='Helvetica 6 bold', fg='Black')
versionNum.place(x=380, y=-3)

#Class operates/works with all the commands and carried out actions.
class actions:

    def updateText(button_id):
        #Function updates text into main entry().
        currentText = entryVariable.get()
        updateText = entryVariable.set(currentText + button_id)

    def clearEntry():
        currentEntry = entryVariable.get()
        clearEntry = entryVariable.set('')

    def evaluate():
        currentText = entryVariable.get()
        getAnswer = eval(str(currentText))
        displayAnswer = entryVariable.set(getAnswer)

    def squareRoot():
        currentText = entryVariable.get()
        squareRoot = sqrt(float(currentText))
        getAnswer = eval(str(squareRoot))
        displayAnswer = entryVariable.set(round(getAnswer,3))

#Class creates the interface.
class buttons:

    #[Zero [0] Button]
zeroButton = Button(master,  width=8, height=3, command=lambda:actions.updateText('0'))
zeroButton_Render=PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\Pamal\Desktop\Documents\Python Folder\Python Projects\Calculator Builds\Calculator Builds\Calculator ++ [1.8.2]\Images\Buttons\zero_Button.png")
zeroButton.config(image=zeroButton_Render, width="145", height="65")
zeroButton.place(x=10, y=410)

#[One [1] Button]
oneButton = Button(master,  width=8, height=3, command=lambda:actions.updateText('1'))
oneButton_Render=PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\Pamal\Desktop\Documents\Python Folder\Python Projects\Calculator Builds\Calculator Builds\Calculator ++ [1.8.2]\Images\Buttons\one_Button.png")
oneButton.config(image=oneButton_Render, width="65", height="65")
oneButton.place(x=10, y=330)

#[Two [2] Button]
twoButton = Button(master,  width=8, height=3, command=lambda:actions.updateText('2'))
twoButton_Render=PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\Pamal\Desktop\Documents\Python Folder\Python Projects\Calculator Builds\Calculator Builds\Calculator ++ [1.8.2]\Images\Buttons\two_Button.png")
twoButton.config(image=twoButton_Render, width="65", height="65")
twoButton.place(x=90, y=330)

#[Three [3] Button]
threeButton = Button(master,  width=8, height=3, command=lambda:actions.updateText('3'))
threeButton_Render=PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\Pamal\Desktop\Documents\Python Folder\Python Projects\Calculator Builds\Calculator Builds\Calculator ++ [1.8.2]\Images\Buttons\three_Button.png")
threeButton.config(image=threeButton_Render, width="65", height="65")
threeButton.place(x=170, y=330)

#[Four [4] Button]
fourButton = Button(master,  width=8, height=3, command=lambda:actions.updateText('4'))
fourButton_Render=PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\Pamal\Desktop\Documents\Python Folder\Python Projects\Calculator Builds\Calculator Builds\Calculator ++ [1.8.2]\Images\Buttons\four_Button.png")
fourButton.config(image=fourButton_Render, width="65", height="65")
fourButton.place(x=10, y=250)

#[Five [5] Button]
fiveButton = Button(master,  width=8, height=3, command=lambda:actions.updateText('5'))
fiveButton_Render=PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\Pamal\Desktop\Documents\Python Folder\Python Projects\Calculator Builds\Calculator Builds\Calculator ++ [1.8.2]\Images\Buttons\five_Button.png")
fiveButton.config(image=fiveButton_Render, width="65", height="65")
fiveButton.place(x=90, y=250)

#[Six [6] Button]
sixButton = Button(master,  width=8, height=3, command=lambda:actions.updateText('6'))
sixButton_Render=PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\Pamal\Desktop\Documents\Python Folder\Python Projects\Calculator Builds\Calculator Builds\Calculator ++ [1.8.2]\Images\Buttons\six_Button.png")
sixButton.config(image=sixButton_Render, width="65", height="65")
sixButton.place(x=170, y=250)

#[Seven [7] Button]
sevenButton = Button(master,  width=8, height=3, command=lambda:actions.updateText('7'))
sevenButton_Render=PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\Pamal\Desktop\Documents\Python Folder\Python Projects\Calculator Builds\Calculator Builds\Calculator ++ [1.8.2]\Images\Buttons\seven_Button.png")
sevenButton.config(image=sevenButton_Render, width="65", height="65")
sevenButton.place(x=10, y=170)

#[Eight [8] Button]
eightButton = Button(master,  width=8, height=3, command=lambda:actions.updateText('8'))
eightButton_Render=PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\Pamal\Desktop\Documents\Python Folder\Python Projects\Calculator Builds\Calculator Builds\Calculator ++ [1.8.2]\Images\Buttons\eight_Button.png")
eightButton.config(image=eightButton_Render, width="65", height="65")
eightButton.place(x=90, y=170)

#[Nine [9] Button]
nineButton = Button(master,  width=8, height=3, command=lambda:actions.updateText('9'))
nineButton_Render=PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\Pamal\Desktop\Documents\Python Folder\Python Projects\Calculator Builds\Calculator Builds\Calculator ++ [1.8.2]\Images\Buttons\nine_Button.png")
nineButton.config(image=nineButton_Render, width="65", height="65")
nineButton.place(x=170, y=170)

#[Decimal [.] Button]
decimalButton = Button(master,  width=8, height=3, command=lambda:actions.updateText('.'))
decimalButton_Render=PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\Pamal\Desktop\Documents\Python Folder\Python Projects\Calculator Builds\Calculator Builds\Calculator ++ [1.8.2]\Images\Buttons\decimal_Button.png")
decimalButton.config(image=decimalButton_Render, width="65", height="65")
decimalButton.place(x=170, y=410)

#[Evaluate Button]
evaluateButton = Button(master,  width=8, height=3, command=lambda:actions.evaluate())
evaluateButton_Render=PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\Pamal\Desktop\Documents\Python Folder\Python Projects\Calculator Builds\Calculator Builds\Calculator ++ [1.8.2]\Images\Buttons\evaluate_Button.png")
evaluateButton.config(image=evaluateButton_Render, width="65", height="145")
evaluateButton.place(x=332, y=330)

#[Clear [CE] Button]
clearButton = Button(master,  width=8, height=3,command=lambda:actions.clearEntry())
clearButton_Render=PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\Pamal\Desktop\Documents\Python Folder\Python Projects\Calculator Builds\Calculator Builds\Calculator ++ [1.8.2]\Images\Buttons\clear_Button.png")
clearButton.config(image=clearButton_Render, width="145", height="65")
clearButton.place(x=10, y=80)

#[Multiply [X] Button]
multiplyButton = Button(master,  width=8, height=3, command=lambda:actions.updateText('*'))
multiplyButton_Render=PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\Pamal\Desktop\Documents\Python Folder\Python Projects\Calculator Builds\Calculator Builds\Calculator ++ [1.8.2]\Images\Buttons\multiply_Button.png")
multiplyButton.config(image=multiplyButton_Render, width="65", height="65")
multiplyButton.place(x=250, y=170)

#[Divide [/] Button]
divideButton = Button(master,  width=8, height=3, command=lambda:actions.updateText('/'))
divideButton_Render=PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\Pamal\Desktop\Documents\Python Folder\Python Projects\Calculator Builds\Calculator Builds\Calculator ++ [1.8.2]\Images\Buttons\divide_Button.png")
divideButton.config(image=divideButton_Render, width="65", height="65")
divideButton.place(x=250, y=250)

#[Add [+] Button]
addButton = Button(master,  width=8, height=3, command=lambda:actions.updateText('+'))
addButton_Render=PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\Pamal\Desktop\Documents\Python Folder\Python Projects\Calculator Builds\Calculator Builds\Calculator ++ [1.8.2]\Images\Buttons\add_Button.png")
addButton.config(image=addButton_Render, width="65", height="65")
addButton.place(x=250, y=330)

#[Minus [-] Button]
minusButton = Button(master,  width=8, height=3, command=lambda:actions.updateText('-'))
minusButton_Render=PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\Pamal\Desktop\Documents\Python Folder\Python Projects\Calculator Builds\Calculator Builds\Calculator ++ [1.8.2]\Images\Buttons\minus_Button.png")
minusButton.config(image=minusButton_Render, width="65", height="65")
minusButton.place(x=250, y=410)

#[SquareRoot [√] Button]
squareRootButton = Button(master,  width=8, height=3, command=lambda:actions.squareRoot())
squareRootButton_Render=PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\Pamal\Desktop\Documents\Python Folder\Python Projects\Calculator Builds\Calculator Builds\Calculator ++ [1.8.2]\Images\Buttons\squareRoot_Button.png")
squareRootButton.config(image=squareRootButton_Render, width="65", height="65")
squareRootButton.place(x=332, y=250)

#[Modulo [%] Button]
moduloButton = Button(master,  width=8, height=3, command=lambda:actions.modulo())
moduloButton_Render=PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\Pamal\Desktop\Documents\Python Folder\Python Projects\Calculator Builds\Calculator Builds\Calculator ++ [1.8.2]\Images\Buttons\modulo_Button.png")
moduloButton.config(image=moduloButton_Render, width="65", height="65")
moduloButton.place(x=332, y=170)


#Locks window size
master.maxsize(415, 495)
master.minsize(415, 495)

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: You should still provide code. Otherwise, I would suggest just adding two entries and just having modulo be the submit button for taking in those two entries and perform the modulo operation on them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service

Comment: Is there a way to do this in 1 entry() rather than having 2 entries?

Answer (score 1):

I recenlty made one (quite advanced, btw I dont use entry but labels, which change text ), but to keep it simple do it like this:
Have one entry, all the buttons ofc.
Whenever you press that button or character like +, % etc, add it to the entry as usual.
Then make a button with "=" text, make a method for it to get the text from the Entry widget and use the built in python function eval. It will do the magic.
If you use IDLE try this in the console:

```
a = "5 % 2" #remember this is a string
eval(a)
#it will print 1
```

Also eval works on very long strings, not only few numbers dont worry.